# How can TypeScript compiler produce an output JS file that a browser can understand?

Tags: typescript

So I want to compile TS files into one JS file that a browser can understand. How do I do that? When I reference index.js in `index.html` file, the browser says that `index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined at index.js:1`. How do I make the TypeScript compiler produce one JS file that a browser can run? Thanks in advance. Regardless of the type of module code generation, the compiler does not produce one a file the browser knows how to process.

**index.ts**

```
import { doSomething } from "./utils";
import { FooBar } from "./foobar";

const foobar = new FooBar();
foobar.foo();

doSomething();
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "amd",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
     "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
     "outFile": "./index.js",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
define("foobar", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var FooBar = /** @class */ (function () {
        function FooBar() {
        }
        FooBar.prototype.foo = function () {
            console.log(this);
        };
        return FooBar;
    }());
    exports.FooBar = FooBar;
});
define("utils", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    function doSomething() {
        console.log('doSomethingg');
    }
    exports.doSomething = doSomething;
});
define("index", ["require", "exports", "utils", "foobar"], function (require, exports, utils_1, foobar_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var foobar = new foobar_1.FooBar();
    foobar.foo();
    utils_1.doSomething();
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Comment: Don't use amd module, use umd

Comment: @Patrick Roberts If I use umd, the compiler says `tsconfig.json:4:5 - error TS6082: Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile`

Comment: If you want to use the `--outFile` flag then continue to use amd, but you need to include [require.js](https://requirejs.org/) in your HTML before including your index.js.